# Why aren't my child nodes getting emptied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that filters inputs and shows them each as a button in a pop-up, but each time the `keyup` event occurs, the search should empty the list and append the new list; instead it just keeps on attaching to the list.

I have tried using `empty()`, but it's not emptying.
I have even tried `html()` and `html('')`, but no luck.

My html:

```
<div class="related-widget-wrapper">
    <select id="id_user" name="user" required="">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="3">abc</option>
        <option value="1">admin</option>
        <option value="2">hello</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My js:

```
var filterInput = '<input type="text" id="customFilter" placeholder="Filter" />';
var filterPopUp = '<div class="filterPop" style="border: 1px solid #000; min-height: 100px; min-width: 200px; display: none; position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%;"></div>';
var newList = "";
$("#id_user")
    .closest(".related-widget-wrapper")
    .append(filterInput, filterPopUp);

$("#customFilter").on("keyup", function() {
    $(".filterPop").empty();
    var input = $(this).val();
    $(".filterPop").show();

    $.each($("#id_user option"), function() {
        var index = $(this).val();
        var val = $(this).text();
        if (val.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) >= 0) {
            newList += '<p class="lists"><button class="filteredList" data-filteredID="' + index + ' value="' + val + '">' + val + "</button></p>";
        }
    });

    $(".filterPop").append(newList);
});
```

I am not entering the `input` field into the html manually, because my Framework does not allow it.

Can someone give me some extra eyes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating to `newList` on `keyup`. You need to empty out `newList` on `keyup` then concatenate in the `$.each()` loop.

```js
var filterInput = '<input type="text" id="customFilter" placeholder="Filter" />';
var filterPopUp = '<div class="filterPop" style="border: 1px solid #000; min-height: 100px; min-width: 200px; display: none; position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%;"></div>';
$('#id_user').closest('.related-widget-wrapper').append(filterInput, filterPopUp);

$('#customFilter').on('keyup', function() {
  $('.filterPop').empty();
  var input = $(this).val();
  $('.filterPop').show();
  var newList = '';

  $.each($('#id_user option'), function() {
    var index = $(this).val();
    var val = $(this).text();
    if (val.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) >= 0) {
      newList += '<p class="lists"><button class="filteredList" data-filteredID="' + index + ' value="' + val + '">' + val + "</button></p>";
    }
  });

  ($('.filterPop').append(newList));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="related-widget-wrapper">
    <select id="id_user" name="user" required="">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="3">abc</option>
        <option value="1">admin</option>
        <option value="2">hello</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: great another dumb mistake I make, I was thinking of empty the html and forgot about emptying the variable too

Comment: @Tsuna haha it's all good, sometimes all you need is a fresh set of eyes on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  $('#customFilter').on(...) try $(filterInput).on(...).

When the element is not parented in the document, jquery won't find it.